# Definition of trace in topological BF-theories

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, principal-bundles, definitions

I very important example of topological field theories are "BF-theories", which are usually defined as follows: Let $G$ be a Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and let $\pi:P\to\mathcal{M}$ be a principal $G$-bundle over a compact smooth manifold $\mathcal{M}$. Furthermore, let $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ be an $\mathrm{Ad}$-invariant non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form on $\mathfrak{g}$. The action of a BF-theory is then defined to be

$$S_{\mathrm{BF}}[B,A]:=\int_{\mathcal{M}}\! \operatorname{tr}(B\wedge F[A]),$$

where $B\in\Omega^{2}(\mathcal{M},\mathrm{Ad}(P))$ is an $\mathrm{Ad}(P)$-valued $(d-2)$-form and where $A\in\Omega^{1}(P,\mathfrak{g})$ is a connection $1$-form. (We view the curvature $F[A]:=\mathrm{d}A+\frac{1}{2}[A\wedge A]$ as an element of $\Omega^{2}(\mathcal{M},\mathrm{Ad}(P))$).

Does anyone know how the trace above is define? I haven't found an explicit definition in the literature. My guess would be the following:

The map $\mathrm{tr}(\cdot\wedge\cdot):\Omega^{d-2}(\mathcal{M},\mathrm{Ad}(P))\times\Omega^{2}(\mathcal{M},\mathrm{Ad}(P))\to\Omega^{d}(\mathcal{M})$ is the map defined locally on an open subset $U\subset\mathcal{M}$ as
\begin{align}\mathrm{tr}(\alpha\wedge\beta)\vert_{U}:=\sum_{a,b=1}^{\mathrm{dim}(G)}(\alpha^{a}\wedge\beta^{b})\langle e_{a},e_{b}\rangle_{\mathrm{Ad}(P)}\in\Omega^{1}(U),\end{align}
where $\{e_{a}\}_{a=1}^{\mathrm{dim}(G)}\subset\Gamma^{\infty}(U,\mathrm{Ad}(P))$ is a local frame and where $\alpha^{a}\in\Omega^{k}(U)$ and $\beta^{b}\in\Omega^{l}(U)$ denote the coordinate forms with respect to this local frame, i.e.
$$\alpha\vert_{U}=\sum_{a=1}^{\mathrm{dim}(G)}\alpha^{a}\otimes e_{a}\hspace{1cm}\text{and}\hspace{1cm}\beta\vert_{U}=\sum_{a=1}^{\mathrm{dim}(G)}\beta^{a}\otimes e_{a}.$$ The bracket $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{\mathrm{Ad}(P)}\in\Gamma^{\infty}(\mathrm{Ad}(P)^{\ast}\otimes\mathrm{Ad}(P)^{\ast})$ denotes the induced vector bundle metric defined by
\begin{align}\langle [p,v],[p,w]\rangle_{\mathrm{Ad}(P)}:=\langle v,w\rangle\end{align}
for all $[p,v],[p,w]\in\mathrm{Ad}(P)$ and for all $p\in P$. This is clearly well-defined and independent of choices. If $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is positive definite and $G$ simple and compact, then $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is necessarily a negative multiple of the Killing form of $\mathfrak{g}$, which is, I guess, the reason why one uses the notation "$\mathrm{tr}$" above. Is this right? Does anyone know?

Comment: Yes, it’s the Killing form.

Comment: Yes, that is clear that $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is proportional to the Killing form, but is the rest also correct?

Comment: The trace is the trace in the adjoint representation, which is the Killing form. Not sure what else you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should ask more precisely: I am asking if my precise definition of $\mathrm{tr}(\cdot\wedge\cdot):\Omega^{d-2}(\mathcal{M},\mathrm{Ad}(P))\times\Omega^{2}(\mathcal{M},\mathrm{Ad}(P))\to\Omega^{d}(\mathcal{M})$ above using the induced bundle metric, local frames, ect. is correct in this very general setting, where $G$ does not need to be a simple Lie group and hence $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ does not need to be a Killing form...

Comment: Ultimately, I think it's a free parameter. If you want things positive definite, you're generally going to end up in the semi-simple case where everything is just a product of compact simple groups, so it's not exciting. It's entirely possible people have examined more exotic situations, however.

Comment: Okay thank you very much for your comments. But still, this is not really my question. My question has nothing to do with Killing forms at all. I just wanted to know if the term "$\mathrm{tr}(B\wedge F[A])$" above is defined as $\mathrm{tr}(\alpha\wedge\beta)\vert_{U}:=\sum_{a,b=1}^{\mathrm{dim}(G)}(\alpha^{a}\wedge\beta^{b})\langle e_{a},e_{b}\rangle_{\mathrm{Ad}(P)}$, where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{\mathrm{Ad}(P)}$ is the induced bundle metric from the given inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{\mathfrak{g}}$. Thats all I want to know...

Comment: Physicists are (often) very prosaic, where the two forms are purely local things valued in matrices (really the adjoint rep), and that's an honest trace. If you want, you can think of the "tr" as a shorthand/schematic, where people aren't worried about global issues, such that when you try to make sense of it, you get the Killing form on the Lie algebra. More generally, you could imagine another invariant pairing on the Lie Algebra to define a different theory, but I think you'd have to get pretty exotic there to potentially get something new that makes physical sense.

Comment: This is a question for mathematicians. I am not asking how I can think of tr.  I am literally only asking if my precise *mathematical* defintion is correct. Thats all.

Comment: See my very first comment.